# Puppet agent on fail function?

Tags: puppet

Do Puppet agents have any type of on failure ability?

I want to create a rule that says if a puppet agent tries to check in fails due to an SSL issue it should remove its SSL certificates and attempt the check-in process again.

I know all the commands I want to run, it's just a matter of finding a way to execute a script on SSL failure.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do Puppet agents have any type of on failure ability?

Not a built-in one, no.  They do *log* failures, of course.  Or I guess the PE version might have something like that -- I wouldn't know.

> I know all the commands I want to run, it's just a matter of finding a
>   way to execute a script on SSL failure.
>
> Any suggestions on how to do this?

When run in `--onetime` mode, the agent's exit code conveys its success or failure, but you'd still have to analyze the log / console output to ascertain the nature of any failure.  To use this for scheduled runs you would want to use an external scheduler such as `cron` to run the agent, rather than letting it run as a daemon itself.  Some folks recommend that as a general good practice.